# Fibonacci Number Formula for nth term

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Hey is there any known combinatorial formula for nth fibonacci number?

(n+1)th fibonacci number is given by summation of **r=0 to (round)n/2**:**C(n-r,r)**
Can someone verify the formula?Help!

Comment: You’ll find proofs of your formula [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079825/prove-that-f-n-n-1-choose-0-n-2-choose-1-n-3-choose-2-ldots-where?rq=1) and at the earlier questions linked from there.

Comment: See the first formula here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics and substitute $n\rightarrow n+1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to incorporate Binet's formula: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html

$$Fib(n) = \frac{\phi^n - \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: I need a combinatorial formula!

Comment: Right, just that I thought I should add a hint which may help you get an answer eventually...